# How to calculate/display relative times (1hr ago, 1 day ago) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to show a little twitter timeline in my website.

I've notice that twitter use the "create_at" tweet's field as follow:

```
"created_at":"Fri Feb 17 14:32:45 +0000 2012"
```

Now, how can I convert this date to my current time zone so I can display how many time has passed since this tweet was created?

I want to output something like "10 min ago", "1 hr ago", "1 month ago"

thank you!

Comment: You don't necessarily need to convert this to your own time zone, right? You could just get the current UTC time and calculate the difference from that time; at 14:42 UTC this time stamp is still going to be 10 minutes ago no matter whether it is 15:42, 23:12, or whatever other time, in your local time zone.

Comment: ok. I can use UTC, but is the twitter timestamp using UTC?

Comment: Yes, note the offset in the timestamp you posted: +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It has a number of date parsing and conversion functions.